# How to get the Azure function app operationid in my .netcore code

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created .netcore 2.0 Azure Function App for Linux.
Can i get the below operationId in my code.
For tracking purpose we need this. While logging exception we want to include this operationId also, in my .net core code. 
[image]

Comment: AFAIK - the operation id will be automatically added to the exceptions from the same operation context. Application Insights already takes care of it for you.

If you really want to get access to it anyway for any custom telemetry you want to write, you should look at how TelemetryInitializer and TelemetryProcessor work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling

Answer (score 2):

I was able to obtain the InvocationId by adding the ExecutionContext to my function parameters:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: how do we create our own invocationid and send it from the azure function to AI?

Comment: `InvocationId` from `ExecutionContext` is NOT the same as `operationId` automatically given to ILogger. For example: `InvocationId=6b3be631-d3ad-4bfa-b70d-3c32c692bc0b`, and `operationId=849be655ea898b45a28c22a538e31723`. `operationId` might be a GUID, but it's different GUID, and formatted without dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.RootId`.

There are some bugs related to it, see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5014